# open a link in the same window with draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to add a link to my chart that I created with draw.io and the problem is the link is opened in an other window.

How can I open a link in the same window with draw.io?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible, the concern is that users will leave the diagram without saving. You can always add it to the [feature requests list](https://draw.uservoice.com/forums/266072-feature-requests), if it gets enough votes it'll be addressed.